# Blank page after enabling secure flag

Tags: java, html, xml, cookies, session-cookies

I have a java web application running in Wildfly 8.0.0.

After enabling secure flag in **standalone.xml**   < session-cookie secure="true"/>
I cant log in anymore via the login form ( action="j_security_check" ), i got a blank page.

I use explorer 11 with IE5 compatibility. There is nothing logged into my application log, and i couldnt find anything with F12.

The URL stays http://localhost:7117/j_security_check , and the page is blank, it should have redirected to http://localhost:7117/index.html

What can go wrong?

How can I debug what is happening?

Answer (score -1):

You should go to your link over HTTPS instead of HTTP.